# Duvida em um SQL DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CD_CLIENTE, CD_CONTRATO, CD_AGRUPADOR  FROM TBP_IMPORTAR_OS_RESIDUO WHERE CD_USUARIO = 0
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu gostaria que quando o campo `CD_AGRUPADOR` fosse igual, trouxesse apenas 1 registro. Eu não posso tirar o `distinct` pois em alguns casos vou ter resultados com valores de agrupador diferente. Por exemplo eu poderia ter um outro registro com os valores
83 - 327 - 0.

Comment: E que dados dos campos CD_CLIENTE e CD_CONTRATO você gostaria que fossem exibidos para tal valor de CD_AGRUPADOR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, você pode usar o `row_number` passando somente o `cd_agrupador`, caso queira pode adicionar mais campos.
Segue o exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT  CD_CLIENTE, 
            CD_CONTRATO, 
            CD_AGRUPADOR,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CD_AGRUPADOR ORDER BY CD_AGRUPADOR) AS RN
    FROM 
        TBP_IMPORTAR_OS_RESIDUO  
    WHERE 
        CD_USUARIO = 0
) AS K
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A função DISTINCT faz você trazer dados distintos, agrupando as mesmas informações na menor quantidade de linhas possível. Se você tem dados distintos no campo CD_CONTRATO, não é possível trazer todas as informações na mesma linha.